# elisp debugger jumping windows around

Tags: window, debugging

I'm trying to use the built-in elisp debugger, invoked by `debug`, and read the source code at the same time. Unfortunately, whenever I continue execution, with either `c` or `d`, the debugger jumps around to a different window -- to the previous window configuration, or some other one that it seems to prefer. It also seems to scroll the source buffers I have open around. This makes it difficult to use.

Is there a way to get it to stop doing so? Has anyone else observed this behavior?

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`? If so, please use `M-x report-emacs-bug`, providing a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem/annoyance. If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: @Drew It sounds as if that is the normal behavior with `edebug-save-windows` on. If he does not like that behavior he can switch it off by pressing `W`. (See my answer.)

Comment: @Tobias: OK; thx. (I use the regular `debug` debugger, and in a dedicated window (frame).)

Comment: @Tobias not sure, edebug doesn't use `d` to continue.

Comment: @npostavs Okay, thanks for the hint. The OP should clarify what he actually uses.

Comment: clarified. I am using the built-in debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I think this behaviour is fine. When executing the next command, the window configuration should be the same as at the moment of break.

Imagine debugging some function whose next step is `thing-at-point`. By moving point to different location one can completely ruine debug session. So debugger is restore point position and window configuration for us.

Another frame may be helpful for you. Just `C-x 5 2` when entered debugger and use that new frame to observe source code while the original frame will be used to command execution.

Also see the [recursive editing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Recursive-Editing.html) documentation. [Debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Debugger.html) is a recursive editing level.