# Don't restore previous window configuration on debugger commands

Tags: debugging

When using the [emacs lisp debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Debugger.html#Debugger), if I

1. invoke it
2. change the window configuration
3. invoke it again (most likely by hitting a breakpoint through the <kbd>d</kbd> command)

my changed window configuration disappears, and it reverts back to the window configuration I had in step 1.

**I would like this not to happen**. Is this possible?

Comment: I do not know whether `debug` allows to switch off saving the windows configuration. But it is easily possible in `edebug` by toggling the menu item `Edebug → Options → Save Windows`. I like `edebug` much more than `debug` because it feels more like other debuggers like `gdb`. But I know that there are people here on Emacs.SE who like `debug` better than `edebug`. So I do not know whether switching to `edebug` is a viable choice for you.

Comment: I think you need to give a more precise recipe, including how you invoke it initially and, especially, how you change the window configuration. Perhaps show some code.

Comment: See similar question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51532/elisp-debugger-jumping-windows-around

Comment: @muffinmad It seems this is a duplicate of that question. However, that question didn't get answered---the answer literally says why the requested functionality is dumb.